# Problem with section name

Tags: beamer, sectioning

[image: why first section name will appear at the title page?]

why first section name will appear at the title page?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\newcommand{\mathnrleg}{\textnormal{\textnrleg}}

\title{\bf \small Comparison between Several Confidence Interval Estimates}
\author{Name: \\{Matric Number: }\\{Supervisor:}\\{Second Reader: }}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\bf Scope of Presentation}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Methodology}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\bf Methodology}
{\bf \textcolor{blue}{\large Gompertz Distribution}}
\begin{itemize}
\item{The Gompertz distribution is one of classical mathematical models that represent survival function based on laws of mortality.}
\item{ It was first introduced by Gompertz as a model for human mortality. }
\end{itemize}
\vspace{1cm}
{\bf \textcolor{blue}{Probability Density Function (pdf)}}
\begin{equation}
f(t;\gamma;\lambda)=\lambda e^{\lambda t +{ \frac{\lambda}{\gamma}} (1-e^{\gamma t})} 
\end{equation}
{where $\lambda= e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 x}$}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: why first section name will appear at the title page?

Comment: can i know how to put the coding in the format? because when i post it's all squeeze together

Comment: To pretty-print some lines of code on this site, simply highlight the lines in question and click on the `{}` "button" in the ribbon above the edit window.

Comment: Please don't use `\bf`. If you really need it, replace it with `\textbf{...}`, but I suggest `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}` instead of doing this manually on each frame.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You've selected the "Frankfurt" beamer theme. One of the features/properties of this theme is that section headers are displayed in the header row on each and every slide -- unless you choose to override this default. Note that the section headers are hyperlinks: Clicking on one of them will take you straight to the slide associated with the `\section` command. Do further note that on page 3 of this sample document, the appearance of the word in the header line switches from grey to white, highlighting the fact that we're now in the section entitled "Methodology".

For more on `beamer` themes, do please consult chapters 15 and 16 of the user guide of the `beamer` package.